Dynamic no. of rows in a google-sheets worksheet
I have a time interval 0 < t < T, and I have a bunch of functions defined on t
t  f1(t)   f2(f1(t), t)   f3(f1, f2, t)   ...
_____________________________________________
0  f1(0)   f2(f1(0), 0)    f3(f1, f2, 0)   ...
0  f1(Δt)  f2(f1(Δt), Δt)  f3(f1, f2, Δt)  ...
...
T  f1(T)   f2(f1(0), T)    f3(f1, f2, T)   ...

If I keep fixed a specific time step Δt, I can organize my computation in a worksheet, using parameters defined elsewhere, and eventually I can plot some results against 0 < t < T.
OTOH, if in turn also the time step Δt depends on those external parameters I don't know how to change the no. of rows in the computational worksheet.
I wonder it's possible using some sort of scripting but my level in scripting google-sheets is below zero :-(

Following this good advice I can generate a time array on the fly, and now I show also a mockup of what I want to do, to reduce the abstraction level of my question...



T
dt
t
cos(t)
t+cos²(t)




1
0.2
0.2






0.4






0.6






0.8






1






I have used =arrayformula(if(C2:C,cos(C2:C),"")),
as suggested here, adding a null string to avoid the display of FALSE,
but a small problem remains, namely no display when there is a 0 in the t column,



T
dt
t
cos(t)
t+cos²(t)




1
0.2
0.000






0.200
0.9800665778
1.160530497




0.400
0.921060994
1.248353355




0.600
0.8253356149
1.281178877




0.800
0.6967067093
1.285400239




1.000
0.5403023059
1.291926582



but when I try to overcome the problem, using =arrayformula(if(isnumber(C2:C),cos(C2:C),"")) then what I get is



T
dt
t
cos(t)
t+cos²(t)




1
0.2
0.000
1
1




0.200
0.9800665778
1.160530497




0.400
0.921060994
1.248353355




0.600
0.8253356149
1.281178877




0.800
0.6967067093
1.285400239




1.000
0.5403023059
1.291926582



to my complete satisfaction.

look no arrayformula =sequence(N+1, 1, 0, Δt)

Good spot - I have updated my answer accordingly. AFAIK the SEQUENCE function in the past did not accept a non-integer for either the start or step parameters (hence my original answer), but this behaviour appears to have been changed.

It's difficult to make specific recommendations given the level of abstraction in your question, but it should be possible to dynamically change the number of rows returned using plain formulas without scripting. For your t column, if you know T and Δt (and they have the same units) then =arrayformula(sequence(T/Δt)*Δt)) will generate the appropriate number of rows (obviously you will need to substitute T & Δt with their actual values or cell references containing the actual values).
Regarding the function columns, you will want to limit them to to the number of filled rows in column t, and there are various approaches for doing this efficiently with array formulas, but again it's difficult to make specific recommendations given the level of abstraction.
EDIT after example given (assuming the example table is found in the top left corner of your sheet):
For column t use =sequence(A2/B2,1,B2,B2) in C2
For column cos(t) use =arrayformula(if(isnumber(C2:C),cos(C2:C),)) in D2
For column t+cos²(t) use =arrayformula(if(isnumber(C2:C),C2:C+D2:D^2,)) in E2
N.B. If you are calculating many functions on many rows, the approach used here to limit the functions to the right number of rows may be suboptimal in terms of calculation time (although it should still work)

Now it less abstract... I hope so.

Your suggestions, as before, put me on the right track, but the result was not completely correct (see my last edit) because one has to use isnumber to distinguish between zero cells and void cells. If you will correct the glitches I could accept your answer.

I've updated the answer as requested to account for t=0.
